# Breaking a loop if a consecutives numbers appears

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, break

I'm having problem with cycles. I have a simple for loop that append random numbers,  what I need is that if a number appears consecutive times break the `for loop`, this is an example.

```
import numpy as np

stop = 3
value = []
for i in range(100):
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 2))
    print(value)
    if value[-stop:] == [0]*stop or value[-stop:] == [1]*stop:
        break
```

What this code does is, I want to do a `for loop 100 times` but if the number 0 or the number 1 appear 3 times in consecutive order in the final of the list, then the loop break, how can I generalized to any random number  without having to add infinite `or` for each random value. I tried using another for loop to iterate trough each value in the appended list, but it's not working, it keeps appending random numbers even if the condition is reached:

```
stop = 3
value = []
for i in range(15):
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 3))
    print(value)
    for i in value:
        if value[-stop:] == [i]*stop: 
            break
```

```
This is what I get in the 10th iteration, here it should stop, since 0 appears three times:
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0]

But it keeps doings iterations and the next one is
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Any idea would be appreciated, if something is not clear, please let me know and I'll edit the question. Thank you, again!

Comment: `[i]*stop` is not going to work, for e.g. in the loop when `i=10`, then `[i]*stop` will give `[10,10,10]` for `stop=3`

Answer (score 0):

Check for all of the values matching the first one of the group:

```
if all(value[pos] == value[-1] for pos in range(-stop, -2)):
```

You're checking the final element, `value[-1]`, against the prior ones from position `-stop` to `-2`.

Look up the `any` and `all` functions; they're very useful for such things.

Comment: Or one can make use of np.where along with all in for the last few values mentioned as stop. Right?

Answer (score 0):

So I understood your question and came up with this answer. Let me know if it works out for you.

```
import numpy as np

stop = 3
value = []
for i in range(15):
    value.append(np.random.randint(0, 3))
    print(value)
    
    if len(value)<stop:
        continue

    if all(np.where(np.array(value[-stop:])==value[-1], True, False)):
        break
```

For one of the random run, I got this as an output:

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Let me know if this works out for you or if you seek some other modification.